# .net sql INSERT multiple rows with addWithValue

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

having this code (which i know the open/executenonquery/close conection in for loop is absolutely horrible).

```
Public Shared Sub salvarDatos(ByRef conexion As SqlConnection, ByRef datos As List(Of DatoBdReloj))

    For i = 0 To datos.Count - 1
        Dim laQuery As String = "Insert INTO MARCADASRELOJ  (COD_MAR_RELOJ,FECHA_RELOJ,HORA_RELOJ,MINUTOS_RELOJ,NRO_RELOJ,NRO_TARJ) " & _
                                "VALUES (@codMarReloj,@fechaReloj,@horaReloj,@minutosReloj,@nroReloj,@nroTarj)"

        Dim datoReloj As DatoBdReloj = datos.Item(i)

        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(laQuery, conexion)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("codMarReloj", datoReloj.tipoMarca)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("fechaReloj", datoReloj.fechaHoraMarcaDT)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("horaReloj", datoReloj.fechaHoraMarcaDT.Hour)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("minutosReloj", datoReloj.fechaHoraMarcaDT.Minute)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("nroReloj", datoReloj.idReloj)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("nroTarj", datoReloj.idUsuario)

        conexion.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conexion.Close()
    Next
End Sub
```

I don't have much experience with .net , but for what i have read using the AddWithValue method i can prevent sql injections and according to the "book" is the right way to do it (tell me if i'm wrong).

using a sentence like "Insert into xxx (x1,x2,x3) values ("val","val","val"),(...),(...)" to insert multiple rows is not an option for me because my database is running with sql 2005.

How can i take away that horrible open/execute/close inside the for loop to insert multiple rows no matter if it's sql 2005 or 2008 and also keep being secure from sql injections by using the AddWithValue Method?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use bulkinsert

The code: [BulkInserter](https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RonnieOverbyGrabBag/blob/master/BulkInserter.cs)
[How to use it](https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RonnieOverbyGrabBag/wiki/Bulk-Inserter)